# Angular directive: return object from collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript

I try to implement a custom directive that list all available plans and allow user to choose one.

When plan is selected, the parent scope must be updated with selected object (it is linked with two way binding)

It should behave exactly the same as angular ng-options does, but I have hard time fighting the Javascript object replacement.

What I have right now works (with some clutter removed):

In HTML:

```
<choose-plan ng-model='plan' plans='plans' choose-plan-title='Premium plans' />
```

In Controller:

```
 $scope.plan = {}  
 Plans.get (resource) ->
   $scope.plans = resource.plans
   return
```

It does not work with `$scope.plan = undefined` obviously, but I look for the solution that does.

In JS (Coffeescript) directive:

```
angular.module('tv-dashboard').directive 'choosePlan', [
  'lodash'
  (lodash) ->
    'use strict'
    restrict: 'E'
    scope:
      plan: '=ngModel'
      plan_collection: '=plans'
      title: '@choosePlanTitle'

    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      # HACK two way binding does not replace the value. Investigate
      scope.choosePlan = (available_plan) ->
        # scope.plan = available_plan # Does NOT update the parent scope binded ng-model
        angular.copy available_plan, scope.plan
        return

      scope.isSelected = (available_plan) ->
        return unless available_plan?
        available_plan.id == scope.plan.id

      presentPlans = (collection) ->
        angular.copy(collection).map (resource_plan) ->
          price_parts = resource_plan.interval_price.split '.'
          resource_plan['integer_price'] = price_parts[0]
          resource_plan['decimal_price'] = price_parts[1]
          resource_plan

      chooseDefaultPlan = (collection) ->
        scope.choosePlan lodash.last collection

      unWatchCollection = scope.$watch 'plan_collection', (collection) ->
        return unless collection? && collection.length > 0

        scope.plans = presentPlans collection
        chooseDefaultPlan scope.plans

        unWatchCollection()
        return
      return
    templateUrl: 'form/choose_plan.html'
]
```

But if you take a look on the `isSelected` function, you notice that i have to compare objects using the id field. Comparison by `==` (`===` in JS) does not return true.

Is there a way I can replace the parent scope `plan` without dancing around with `angular.copy available_plan, scope.plan` and forced to use the `id` field comparison?

Comment: You should `require: "ngModel"` - not use it as as scope two-way bound variable. See [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#example) on how to create a custom input control, which is essentially what you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `require: 'ngModel'` to inject the model attached to the element or its parent element on which the directive is bound to. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AXBut/156/).

Comment: I am sure that I tried that before. And it does not work for the objects. Will provide example soon

Comment: alright, I found the issue. The problem was I was using the ui-router abstract state with controller.
All child state reuse that controller.

But the scope did not update. When i explicitly defined the controller in template or move the `controller` definition form abstract state to child state, it magically begin to work.

Comment: yes, but still can not make an example which fails. In the app I have to use the controller on abstract state to share it between child states. Parent scope does not updates it this case.

Comment: any guess why that may happen?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to share an object and write into its properties

```cs
$scope.plan = {
  // value: set in directive
}

scope.choosePlan = (available_plan) ->
  scope.plan.value = available_plan
  return

scope.isSelected = (available_plan) ->
  return unless available_plan?
  available_plan == scope.plan.value
```

Your code as jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6tmhfu/1/

Fixed code as jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6tmhfu/3/

Comment: `angular.copy ` which I used in initial example is a better solution.
I use the `require "ngModel"` right now. It works for child controllers. But not for the controllers defined on abstract states.